# Convert datatable to IEnumerable<T> to pass to Result<T>(IEnumerable<T> data);

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, generics, datatable

I have an object called `Result<T>` that has a constructor which accepts an argument of `IEnumerable<T>`. I'd like to be able to pass in a datatable if possible.

I tried `datatable.AsEnumerable()`, but where I bind to the data it was complaining that 'MyProperty' is not a field or property on type 'DataRow' - which makes sense since 'MyProperty' isn't a property on 'DataRow', but it was a column in my datatable.

Is there a way to convert a datatable to something that I can pass into the Result object and still have it bind to, say, a gridview?

Comment: Why dont you just use Entity Framework ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using Linq to convert the datatable into an array of anonymous objects.

```
Dim objs = From row In dt Select New With {
    .Id = row.Field(Of Integer)("Id"),
    .Count = row.Field(Of Integer)("Count")
}
```

Then I created a generic function to use type inference to get the anonymous object array into the Result object's constructor

```
Private Function GetResult(Of T)(ByVal data As IEnumerable(Of T)) As Result(Of T)
    Return New Result(Of T)(Nothing, data)
End Function
```

Called using `Dim result = GetResult(objs)`

Answer (score 3):

If you can write a function that can construct an instance of the object that has 'MyProperty' using a single DataRow, then you can do it like this:

```
datatable.AsEnumerable().Select(MyConversionFunction);
```

Comment: IIRC, it's dtatable.Rows.AsEnumerable()

Comment: @Cylon Cat - Nope, it's [actually not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
```

Comment: What would that do? Wouldn't you still run into the same problem? 'MyProperty' wouldn't be a property on a DataRow instance.

Comment: well, that should give you the rows, and you can indeed access each column on each row, eg in a for each loop that would be `For Each row As DataRow In rows
 Dim val = row("MyProperty")
Next`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert your typed datatable to a EnumerableRowCollection you can use the following:

```
EnumerableRowCollection<YourTypedRow> typedRowCollection = datatable.AsEnumerable().Cast<YourTypedRow>();
```